# How to get user name using Windows authentication in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, windows-authentication, windows-security

I want to get user name using Windows authentication

Actually, I implemented "Sign in as different user", when click this button Windows security will appear there we can give credentials.

In that time if I give some other credential it is taking current user name only.
How to get that given credential user name from windows security?

Host application in IIS then anonymous authentication has disabled and windows authentication was enabled.

**web.config:**

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <identity impersonate="true"/>
  <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
```

</system.webserver>

**.cs**

Here I am getting the default User name always

```
string fullName = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 46):

These are the different variables you have access to and their values, depending on the IIS configuration.

**Scenario 1:** Anonymous Authentication in IIS with impersonation off.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name    SERVER1\IUSR_SERVER1 
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated           False                    
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name                –                        
System.Environment.UserName                           ASPNET                   
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name  SERVER1\ASPNET
```

**Scenario 2:** Windows Authentication in IIS, impersonation off.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name    MYDOMAIN\USER1   
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated           True             
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name                MYDOMAIN\USER1   
System.Environment.UserName                           ASPNET           
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name  SERVER1\ASPNET
```

**Scenario 3:** Anonymous Authentication in IIS, impersonation on

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name    SERVER1\IUSR_SERVER1 
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated           False                    
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name                –                        
System.Environment.UserName                           IUSR_SERVER1           
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name  SERVER1\IUSR_SERVER1
```

**Scenario 4:** Windows Authentication in IIS, impersonation on

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name    MYDOMAIN\USER1
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated           True          
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name                MYDOMAIN\USER1
System.Environment.UserName                           USER1         
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name  MYDOMAIN\USER1
```

Legend
`SERVER1\ASPNET`: Identity of the running process on server.
`SERVER1\IUSR_SERVER1`: Anonymous guest user defined in IIS.
`MYDOMAIN\USER1`: The user of the remote client.

[Source](http://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net/)

Comment: Total rip-off from the link provided by @KaushikGhosh. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459055/4821032

Comment: What about the Identity of the running process on server? Does it have to be defined as "Authenticated User"? Please explain more about this.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Could you post a new question and maybe link it form a comment? I will have a look at it. :-)

Answer (score 38):

You can get the user's [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx) object under Windows Authentication by:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

and then you can get the information about the user like identity.Name.

Please note you need to have HttpContext for these code.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I tried this but not working..if I give any wrong password in windows security it is taking how to solve this?

Comment: You mean wrong password input at the Windows Auth dialog? It should not allow you pass authentication.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

`Identity` returns an `IPrincipal`

Here is the link to the Microsoft [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the configuration of the application as well as on IIS as this gentleman in the below link has rightfully explained. Please see his article below

http://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net/

Comment: Although it doesn't direclty answer the question AND actually is a "link-only" question, it really is a good read. Maybe one could write a proper answer and we accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the `Name` from `WindowsIdentity`:

```
var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
return Ok(user);
```

Comment: Yo get the Identity of the running process on server?

Comment: This only works if you use impersonation. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/xh507fc5(v=vs.100). If you have a reason to do so, then it is correct, but otherwise, you should probably not use impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

I think because of the below code you are not getting new credential

```
string fullName = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

You can try **custom login page**.

Comment: I meant design new log in page. you can try it active directory authentication using windows authentication. Which browser you are running your page on?

Comment: custom login page sample ?

Comment: is the same than HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity?.Name; ?

Answer (score 0):

Username you get like this:

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity?.Name;
```

Answer (score -1):

declare below code in your View page / _Layout.cshtml:

```
@using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

@{
    var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
    var userName = @principal.GivenName + " " + @principal.Surname;
}
```