# Getting username of a webform

Tags: c#, iis

I have a webform, and I am trying to make a log of who is using it. All the research I did, was all about using on a local box, not through IIS.

```
using System.Security.Principal;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string curuser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        }
```

**Where I get the Output:**

```
tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + CurUser);
```

**Output displayed:**

> 12/1/2017 4:13:18 PM: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

I am assuming it is something silly and dumb. Thanks guys

Note: I have 'Windows Authentication' enabled within IIS for this site.

Comment: I don't see how that code would produce that output.  Or any output.

Comment: @David updated post with how I am getting the output.

Comment: What is `tw`?  What is `CurUser`?  (It's a distinctly different variable than `curuser`.)  Where does that new code execute?  I suspect you're making some mistakes or false assumptions in your testing, essentially invalidating the question.

Comment: @David tw is just a Textwriter, CurUser is the string where I am storing it. The date/time was not in the original post, because I did not include the entire output I was getting, just the relevant piece. Also, I figured out why I was not getting errors, I did not revert back after I was testing. Updating top post, with current information... sorry

Comment: Please don't change the question such that it invalidates existing answers.  This renders the question and answers unusable for future readers.  You are certainly invited to add more information to the question, or even to open additional questions.  But completely changing the original question after it's been answered is considered vandalizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever or wherever `CurUser` is, it's an instance of a `Label`.  It's *not* your `curuser` variable that you declared in `Page_Load` and then never used.

When you try to output an object as a string, the system internally invokes the `.ToString()` implementation on that object.  Unless overridden (and `Label` doesn't override it), the default implementation for `.ToString()` (inherited from `System.Object`) is to output the name of the type.  In this case `"System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label"`.

(Makes sense.  After all, how would the system inherently know how a complex object, particularly any custom object you could write, *should* be represented as a string?)

Don't output an unrelated object, output the value:

```
string curuser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + curuser);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I forgot to correct. I am now getting results that make more sense. The output (now that its correct) is: 12/1/2017 4:21:41 PM: IIS APPPOOL\WebApp - shouldnt that be the Windows Credentials connecting to the app?

Comment: @dwb: I'm not 100% certain without testing it, but I *suspect* that what you're grabbing is the user context of the application itself and not the connected web user.  Try this instead: `string curuser = User.Identity.Name;`  (`User` is a property on the `Page` object.)

Comment: That one just shows a blank response. 12/1/2017 4:32:11 PM:- Also, I forgot to mention, the users are not logging into the site, not sure if maybe thats the issue, and I am going the wrong direction.

Comment: @dwb: This also looks potentially helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676312/how-to-get-user-name-using-windows-authentication-in-asp-net

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. Thanks for the direction.