# login with domain controller and without domain controll

Tags: authorization

I tried to access the username  DomainControlle
I succeeded with the following code

```
Request.ServerVariables.Get("logon_user");
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name;
```

with web.config

```
     <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users ="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

If the configuration code is not in the server, the code will not work

My problem is this. Internal users of the domain are working. Users outside the domain give an error. Unauthorized
I want to direct the domain's internal users to the next login page. And users outside the domain can see the login page

Thanks for your help

Comment: System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
        Response.Write(user.Identity.Name);

&

Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].ToString());

Both the above method works when i run the page from visual studio.

However when i run the page from IIS or any other server, it gives me a blank value

Please help me as i cannot begin this project without solving this issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676312/how-to-get-user-name-using-windows-authentication-in-asp-net